# View can not be anchored to the parent CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, coordinator-layout

I just updated to appcompat library from 23.1.1 to 23.2 and now application stopped working on java.lang.IllegalStateException: View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout
```

Crash comes from `resolveAnchorView` method of `CoordinatorLayout` when parent (CoordinatorLayout is not in edit mode). Layout is used as root element in base activity and contains different layouts (toolbar, progressbar and finally relativelayout with inflated layout of activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/base_activity__main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/shared__color_primary">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/base_activity__progress_bar_top"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/base_activity__switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/base_activity__progress_bar_top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/base_activity__progress_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_loading"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/base_activity__progress_bar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/base_activity__main_content_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </ViewSwitcher>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_activity__add_button__container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where is this layout `base_activity__main_layout`

Comment: it is coordinator laytout contains this xml, but problem was caused with this line  app:layout_anchor="@id/base_activity__main_layout", but I still do not understand why

Comment: so the co ordinator layout is in a different file? and you are adding this layout that you have attached in your question by inflating it in a fragment?

Comment: no it is single xml file, example in question inside coordinatorlayout

Comment: is this `base_activity__add_button__container` a direct child of the cordinator layout?

Comment: full layout is updated in question now

Comment: seems that to "layout_anchor" must be assigned a control that is child of the CoordinatorLayout and not the coordinator layout itself. Try to set layout_anchor to ViewSwitcher for example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot set the layout anchor attribute to the co ordinator layout itself `app:layout_anchor="@id/base_activity__main_layout",` this is wrong, you need to set some direct child of the co ordinator as this layouts anchor

Comment: thanks , that works for me, in new support library version , we cannot direct anchor coordinator layout

Comment: exactly as Luci said 13 hours ago, thnx

Comment: @jakub its been long enough looks like luci doesn't want to post her answer, you may as well mark this right